# unary increment doesn't work?

Tags: java, for-loop, infinite-loop, post-increment, unary-operator

```
public class Temp { 
public static  void main(String[] args) { 
   for (int i = 0; i < 10;){
       i = i++;
       System.out.println("Hello world");
   }   
 }
}
```

why `i` does not get increment as we are incrementing it still it does not get increment
as we can see in the for loop when we are doing post-increment it isnt working and it goes to infinite loop, when we are doing pre-increment 
`i = ++i` its working properly and even when we are doing like `i = (i=i+1)`  here also it working 
but not when we are doing post increment 
i is assign to i++ and that time value of i was 0 but immediately after it got increment by 1 than it should reflect on next loop iteration
why it is not reflecting?

Comment: First you evaluate `i`, then increment `i`, then assign the evaluated result (the first one) to `i` making it stay as it was.

Answer (score 1):

`i++` returns the original value of `i` (prior to the increment), so if you assign that value back to `i`, you revert `i` back to its original value.

You don't have to assign `i++` or `++i` to `i`.